# why the size of all SqlParameters generated by VS2010 are set to 0?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

why the size of all SqlParameters generated by VS2010 are set to 0, while when I look in the dataset all the columns are set to different sizes but when I read it from sqldataadapter they are all set to 0. Isn't it going to make some other issues in future? I mean, I have many sqlparameter with NVarChar types that they are generated by VS2010 and the size is 0!!! 
Any other information in this area will be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx

"If not explicitly set, the size is inferred from the actual size of the specified parameter value."

My guess is that the size has not been explicitly set; thus it appears as the default for an Int32, which is zero, thus the size will be inferred from the actual size of the value.

(To rephrase: they're not set to 0, they're just not set at all)

Comment: It is actually putting 0 anyway. So you cannot sey they are not set to zero or not set at all. Since I have anothere class generated by 2008 and it has all the parameters as well. So nything else you might wanna add up?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand exactly what you're saying here.  It's not possible to have 'not set' or null for an `Int32` field like this `Size` - if you don't set it, it remains at the default, which is 0.