# Where does dataadapter will find its sqlparameters information from?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a table, I add a dataadapter to it and it has all the commands. There are lists of paramters for update,insert and delete. I wonder where does the Visual Studio find the related informatio on the size of the parameter? Since I believe it is reading from a wrong place or I did not set someting correctly. While the corresponding NvarChar column in dataset and database table is having the size of 20, in dataadapter it is all 0! Any related info would be appreciated since I am in such a hurry!

Comment: Didn't the answer to you other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472980/why-the-size-of-all-sqlparameters-generated-by-vs2010-are-set-to-0 help?

Comment: No because no one answered the second one on that post. Can u?

Answer (score 0):

You have told Visual Studio where to find the table, the rest is "database-reflection".

Comment: So based on what you are saying, If I do have the table columns correctly set, there is something wrong in Visual Studio for finding the right dataset table?

Comment: Could it be because we still use SQL2005 with VS2010 and that database reflection is not working?

Comment: @amir: no, VS2010 and SQL-Server 2005 work together well. Have you reconfigurated your select-command? (right-click -> configure ...)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have a component which has only sqlconnection and a dataadapter, nothing more! I have reconfigured some of my components since they include business objects. Does this help?

Comment: It is weird, I add datadapter, I use a query builder to generate the commands, I go to the code, all the sizes of parameters are not what they should be. all 0! Any other opinion? In this case I build from scratch!

Comment: @amir: you've done that in the dataset-designer of VS? Are the datacolumns all visible in the datatable and the maxlength property of each column is 0? Try to delete all columns but primary key and reconfigure it. That should delete all old. If this doesnt help you should restart VS.

Comment: sorry, did you got me wrong? I guess so, in detail: in design mode of a component, I add sqldataadapter, for declaring the select command I use a query Builder and I will select a table from my database and I finish the wizard. But When I go to parameters after this wizard, all of the sizes are 0 while if i add the table in dataset or if you look the database you will see columns in that table are having different maxlength but it is declared in parameters collection in sqlcommand of that component. Why is that?

Comment: @amir: the Querybuilder is a toy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing the DataAdapter Update method with a database update. I'm pretty sure it cannot be used that way. You need to make a connection with your database and loop through the rows of your datatable and perform whatever operation needs to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set the update command yourself in code, then either the `DataSet` or `CommandBuilder` will automatically generate the update command as detailed in the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbdataadapter.updatecommand%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It is not the matter of command, it is matter of the size of the parameters if you read the last comment of mine on the previous answer!